# How to join every child entity in a tree structure in typeorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

I have a tree structure of categories. Those categories have relations to other tables.

```
import {Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToOne, OneToMany} from "typeorm";
@Entity()
export class Category {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    description: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => Category, category => category.children)
    parent: Category;

    @OneToMany(type => Category, category => category.parent)
    children: Category[];

    @OneToMany(type => Site, site => site.category)
    sites: Site[];
}
```

My code to get the tree:

```
console.log(await getConnection().getTreeRepository(Category).findTrees());
```

The result:

```
[
  Category {
    pk: 8,
    id: '1C606380-020A-4CED-8EBA-AA1C9C16FCF2',
    title: 'Category EXPLICIT',
    createdBy: 'SAFETYMANUAL',
    createdAt: 2021-07-27T19:57:03.213Z,       
    hidden: false,
    orderValue: 0,
    deletionDate: null,
    childCategories: [ [Category] ]
  }
]
```

I want to load the whole tree WITH the relations, in this case with the array of Sites. Setting eager to true doesn't change anything. I only get back the tree without the sites array. Is there a possibility to join in tree structures?

Comment: hey, I am also not able to load the relations in the tree. Have you found any solution for this ?

Comment: @rickster I implemented a pull request that enables loading relations. I added an answer to my question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a pull request that enables loading relations for trees:

```js
const treeCategoriesWithRelations = await repository.findTrees({ relations: ["sites"] });
// automatically joins the sites relation
```

Comment: is it available in latest version of nest i.e 8.1.1 ?? Because I am not able to use it. Its giving me error. `Expected 0 arguements. Recieved 2` like this

Comment: @rickster Possibly not available in nest yet - it is a pretty new feature but is released in the most current typeorm version. Nest might not have updated to the newest typeorm version yet.

Comment: Ohh okay. Thanks.

Comment: Does vice-versa work for same?
I've Products having multiple categories, I just need to get "parentID" in category relation.
When specify (id, name, parentId) in addSelect, it gives only id and name but excludes parentId column.
Can you assist here..!